# R: How to get the e1071 (SVM) results from all cross validations (or at least one) for deeper evaluation

Tags: r, performance, classification, svm, libsvm

I use e1071 package for SVM multiclass classification on text documents. The usual evaluation of multiclass classification models is made with agreement, precision (micro, macro), recall (micro, macro), f1 (micro, macro), etc.. I would like to get the results from 10-fold cross validations for this evaluations (manually implemented). Is there a posibility to do this?

If yes, can you name the function, functions?

If no, is there any work around?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the answer here is no.  However it is a trivial task to write a bash script to do this manually! Good luck.